# How to convert 8-bit integer to Hex color value?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert 8-bit integer to Hex color value. (e.g. FFFFFF)

The 8-bit color integer is generated with the following formula:

```
color = ( [red] * -65536) + ( [green] * -256) + ( [blue] * -1)
```

In C, it is done by `sprintf(colorbuf, "#%6.6x", color);`

How can I convert this 8-bit integer value to Hex color value in Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an integer (in this case, it looks like it would be negative, but I will let you deal with that) you can do

```
color.toString(16)
```

and it will turn it in to a hex string.

```
// White
color = (255 * -65536) + (255 * -256) + (255 * -1) => -16777215
color.toString(16) => "-ffffff"
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
function colorToHex(color) {
if (color.substr(0, 1) === '#') {
    return color;
}
var digits = /(.*?)rgb\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\)/.exec(color);

var red = parseInt(digits[2]);
var green = parseInt(digits[3]);
var blue = parseInt(digits[4]);

var rgb = blue | (green << 8) | (red << 16);
return digits[1] + '#' + rgb.toString(16).padStart(6, '0');
```

};

Comment: error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null